# Making unambiguous concatenate when retrieving info for email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, concatenation

The aim is to check individual worksheets for a list of dates in a range, and then send an email listing these dates to an email address located in the sheet.

The current code concatenates the dates in the current sheet as well as the dates on the previous sheet, instead of just the dates found on this sheet.

I'm struggling to make it uni-vocal,  tried putting "ws." before each aCell instruction but get compile error.

```vb
Sub Mail_Outlook()
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As Variant
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim string1 As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
       
    For Each wsName In Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")
        
        Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
            
        'retrieve all missing dates
        For Each aCell In ws.Range("Aa1:Aa1000")
    
            If aCell.Value <> "" Then
                i = i + 1
                If i <> 1 Then
                    string1 = string1 & ",   " & aCell.Value
    
                Else
                    string1 = aCell.Value
                End If
                    
            End If
            
        Next
    
        'send email
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
        strbody = "Good day " & ws.Range("E3").Cells & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          string1 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "(This is an automated message)" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Best regards" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        With OutMail
            .To = ws.Range("E5").Text
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ""
            .Body = strbody
            'You can add a file like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display   'or use .Send
        End With
        
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

From the OP's comments:
code as is produces no errors, but e.g. the second email contains the string for the first sheet and second sheet, rather than just the second sheet.

Comment: what line are you getting the error? line number?

Comment: The `Next` you have is a `Next aCell`. You need a `Next wsname` underneath it.

Comment: @Miguel - code as is produces no errors, but e.g. the second email contains the string for the first sheet and second sheet, rather than just the second sheet.

Comment: @Jeeped There is a Next at the bottom already, it correctly writes the email from each sheet, but the issue is as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero the string before going into the second iteration of the loop.

```
For Each wsName In Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")

    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    string1  = vbNullString    'reset string1 to a zero-length string for each ws

     'retrieve all missing dates
     For Each aCell In ws.Range("Aa1:Aa1000")
       'all the rest of the concatenation code
     next aCell

    'all the rest of the email code
Next wsName
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this solution does the trick for me! Greatly appreciated.